# force:source:deploy --coverageformatters?

Tags: apex, unit-test, salesforcedx

Hi the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm#cli_reference_force_source_deploy) specifies a `--coverageformatters` parameter for `sfdx force:source:deploy` but I can't find any information about what the values for this can be. Where can I find documentation on the values for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

harte,

The possible values are:

- clover
- cobertura
- html-spa
- html
- json
- json-summary
- lcovonly
- none
- teamcity
- text
- text-summary

Source: Release Notes for 7.153.0: https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/blob/main/releasenotes/sfdx/README.md